# Laravel: Private URL for file that I can use with an API

Tags: laravel, api, model-view-controller, controller

I'm trying to create a URL for a file that I can use with an API. The file must be private, which is why I can't just use a public file URL.

I created a custom link that downloads an EPUB file, but for some reason it's not working with my epub reader API.

```
public function index($id)
{
    $product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();
    $contents = Storage::get($product->epub);                     
    $filepath = storage_path('app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.($product->epub));
    return response()->download($filepath);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different why to make data accessable through an URL?
I appreciate every help I can get.

Comment: provide error, please

Comment: Try using `Storage::path($product->epub)` instead of `storage_path('app'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.($product->epub));`

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either :/ The download link itself works but not when I insert it into my API. 

(and I know for a fact that my API is set up properly, as links to public files work just fine)